# Adding label outside the donut graph in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a interactive donut chart like http://bl.ocks.org/erichoco/6694616 . I want the values outside the donut as a label. Value should be outside for each arc or path.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Have you see [this](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799)?

Comment: Where is your code?